# Python & Selenium: Unable to locate and click Facebook like and share button

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to locate the 'Like' and 'Share' button on facebook pages with xpath, however after the facebook page loads, the python script execution is complete and the like button is not clicked.

I got the like button xpath from facebook page.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

def connect():
    driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/mytheoryofevolution/")
    time.sleep(4)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\javed\PycharmProjects\click-website\drivers\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)


connect()

like_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"likeButton")]')

for like in like_buttons:
    print(like)
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tYou don't need

```py
break
```

because when it will start the for loop you will get the first item and then the loop will break

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\javed\PycharmProjects\click-website\drivers\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)

def connect():
    driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/mytheoryofevolution/")
    time.sleep(4)
    like_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"likeButton")]')

    for like in like_buttons:
        print(like)

connect()
```

Comment: @lakavos, I have tried your answer still unable to click on like button, it just opens the facebook post page and stops.

Comment: Your terminal doesn't print anything ?

Comment: It seems that you are targeting like buttons the wrong way

Comment: No, terminal does not print anything

Comment: You are selecting the like buttons with the wrong way. The only solution I found is an old issue here and the solution was to use JS